# Viability for thermoelectric cooling in a computer setting

Tags: computers, cooling

I have a very powerful server computer that needs to be running 24/7, and the twin watercooled (with multiple fans) CPU is still overheating largely because the room it's stored in gets quite hot in the summertime. Is thermoelectric cooling a viable method to help cool the radiators faster, or is refrigeration the only way to improve the setup without completely changing the environment?

Comment: Thermoelectric cooling is possible, but I don't think it would be all that efficient. Peltier cells are not particularly efficient and you can get better performance per input energy out of a conventional vapor-compression heat pump.

Comment: That said, it is used for low-load things, for which the benefits outweigh the detriments. But from the sound of it your application would be comparatively high-load, and Peltier cells lose efficiency at higher loads.

Comment: underclocking the cpus and lower the voltage to them will increase stability and lower heat

Answer (score 1):

The "efficiency" for a Peltier as a heat pump is defined by the COP (Coefficient of Performance) which is heat pumped versus power input. This is variable, and at a maximum for very small differential temperatures. Here is an example of a performance curve of COP versus current.
[image]

You can see that for a delta T of 10 degrees the COP is almost 3 - at a current that is a fraction of its maximum. More realistically, at 50% of max current you get a COP of about 1.25 so 100W of Peltier input will pump 125W of heat at that temperature differential. You will have to do the sums yourself, but [here is a useful article](http://www.meerstetter.ch/compendium/tec-peltier-element-design-guide)